# How can we convert double sums to single sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, special-functions

Let's say that $n\to A(n),B(n)$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N^2}$. This would be the inverse of a [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

The canonical example would be

$B(n)= n-\frac{1}{2}\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}\rfloor \lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}{2} \rfloor $

$A(n) = \lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}\rfloor-B\left(n\right)$

Then is it the case that

$$\sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{a=0}^\infty{f(a,b)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(A(n),B(n))?$$

I assume that if I am given that LHS is absolutely convergent the equality holds for any pairing function. I would guess that this is overkill however.

If $\sum_{b=0}^\infty \sum_{a=0}^\infty{f(a,b)}$ is conditionally convergent we still may be able to find a suitable $A(n),B(n)$.

**Questions**

1) What conditions are required for this equality to hold?

2) I don't know a whole lot about double sums. Is this a standard technique? Where can I learn more?

3) Where can I find more pairing functions? I can't imagine that the one above is the most convenient to work with...

**Example**

Let's say $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{(a+1)^2(b+1)^2}$

Then it's easy enough (Given we know the solution of the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)) to find the left hand side is $\pi^4/36$. But to find what the righthand side looks like is going to be tricky. We have a new series of rationals that approaches $\pi^4/36$. It's $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\dots$ it doesn't have such a nice pattern to it because of our selection of the functions $A,B$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PairingFunction.html

Comment: http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2gj7u89h6w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're initially presenting this as a double sum is irrelevant.  In the end, this is just about rearrangements of series.  Different bijections of $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N^2$ correspond to different rearrangements of the series.

The [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) says that a conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to converge to any real number, or diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.